# ifstream not reading the same characters as they are written in the file

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emYmg.jpg)

[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TjQp.jpg)

Simple explanation: ifstream's get() is reading the wrong chars (console is different from file) and I need to know why.

I am recording registers into a file as a char array. When I write it to the file, it writes successfully. I open the file and find the chars I intended, except notepad apparently shows unicode character 0000 ( NULL) as a space.

For instance, the entries

```
id = 1000; //an 8-byte long long
name = "stack"; //variable size
surname = "overflow"; //variable size
degree = "internet"; //variable size
sex = 'c'; //1-byte char
birthdate = 256; //4-byte int
```

become this on the file:

```
&      èstackoverflowinternetc
```

or, putting the number of unicode characters that disappear when posted here between brackets:

```
&[3]|      [1]è|stack|overflow|internet|c|  [1] | //separating each section with a | for easier reading. Some unicode characters disappear when I post them here, but I assure you they are the correct ones
SIZE|    ID    | name| surname| degree |g| birth
```

(writing is working fine and puts the expected characters)

Trouble is, when the console in the code below prints what the buffer is reading from the file, it gives me the following record (extra spaces included)

```
         Þstackoverflowinternetc
```

Which is bad because it returns me the wrong ID and birthdate. Either "-21" and "4747968" or "Ù" and "-1066252288". Other fields are unnaffected. Weird because size bytes show up as empty space in the console, so it shouldn't be able to split name, surname, degree and sex.

```
ifstream infile("alumni.freire", ios::binary);
if(infile.is_open()){
    infile.seekg(pos, ios::beg);
    int size;
    size = infile.get();
    char charreg[size];
    charreg[0] = size;

    //testing what buffer gives me
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        charreg[i] = infile.get();
        cout << charreg[i];
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: to explain better what I did:
I get the entries on the first "code" from user input and use them as parameters when creating a "reg" class I implemented. The reg class then does (adequatly, I've already tested it) the conversion to strings, and calculates a hidden four-element char array containing instance size, name size, surname size and degree size. When the program writes the class on-file, it is written perfectly, as I showed in the second "code" section. (If you do the calculations you'll see '&' equals the size of the entire thing, for example). When I read it from the file, it appears differently on console for some reason. Different characters. But it reads the right amount of characters because "name", "surname" and "degree" appear correctly.

EDIT n2: I made "charreg[]" into an int array and printed it and the values are correct. I have no idea what's happening anymore.

EDIT n3: Apparently the reason I was getting the wrong chars is that I should have used unsigned chars...

Comment: First of all, C++ doesn't actually have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), there's one compiler that have it as a non-portable extension of the language. Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Secondly, [the `get` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) while it's declared to return an `int`, it's because that's needed for the eof check (which you really should have). It really reads a single character, which is typically an 8-bit byte. If the size stored in the file isn't an 8-bit byte (but something larger) then the size you read will not be correct. And of course, if you want to read raw binary data you have to remember to open the file in `bin` mode (which you don't show us, please always show us a [mcve]).

Comment: I know it doesn't. But it doesn't matter, I used strings and converted them to a char array when writing them on the file. The second, third and fourth bytes of the register describe the sizes of the fields "name", "surname" and "degree", which together with the size bytes themselves, are the parts of the code that are actually working.

Comment: You need to better describe the file format you're working with.

Comment: If your ID is 8 byte long, why you read byte by byte ?

Comment: Show us how you're writing to this specific file, because with the example you've given I can tell you that those characters are wrong for an integer of 1000. Based on those characters the integer actually results to 538976294 (big endian).

Answer (score 0):

The idea to write, as is, your structure is good. But your approach is wrong.

You must have something to separate your fields.
For example you know that your ID is 8 byte long, great ! You can read 8 bytes :

```
long long id;
read(fd, &id, 8);
```

In your example you got -24 because you read the first byte of the full id number.

But for the rest of the file, how can you know the length of the first name and the last name ? 
You could read byte by byte until you find an null byte.

But I suggest you to use a more structured file.
For example, you can define a structure like this :

```
long long id;        // 8 bytes
char firstname[256]; // 256 bytes
char lastname[256];  // 256 bytes
char sex;            // 1 byte
int  birthdate;      // 4 bytes
```

With this structure you can read and write super easily :

```
struct my_struct s; 
read(fd, &s, sizeof(struct my_struct)); // read 8+256+256+1+4 bytes
s.birthdate = 128;
write(fd, &s, sizeof(struct my_struct));// write the structure
```

Of course you loose the "variable length" of the first name and last name. Do you really need more than 100 chars for a name ?

In a case you really need, you could introduce an header over each variable length value. But you loose the ability to read everything at once.

```
long long id;
int foo_size;
char *foo;
```

And then to read it :

```
struct my_struct s;
read(fd, &s, 12); // read the header, 8 + 4 bytes
char foo[s.foo_size];
read(fd, &s, s.foo_size);
```

You should define what exactly you need to save. Define a precise data structure that you can easily deduce at read, avoid things like "oh, let's read until null-byte".

I used C function to explain you because it's much more representative. You know what you read and what you write.
Start to play with this, and then try the same with c++ streams/function

Comment: The thing is that the first 4 bytes already have the sizes of this particular instance of the register and its variable size components. (as none of those fields will reasonably surpass 255 bytes). My real problem is that ifstream is not getting the correct characters from the file, but it reads the correct amount of them (console is showing name, surname and degree correctly)

Comment: Check my answer, it resolves the issue of not reading the write characters.

Comment: Hasengeist yes I got it. For me your problem comes from the approach.
You are not supposed to read byte by byte. Specially an 8 bytes number. You read it in a wrong way. And so as @D.Foley suggest, you write it maybe in a wrong way too.
Review your method, try a more basic way as I suggested, just to train yourself with it. 
ifstream read the right number of bytes, yes, but you dont use them in the right way.
Printing the first byte will not give you 1000 but just the first byte. So the sign and ect...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are writing back information to the file but here is how I would do that, I'm hoping this is a fairly simple way of doing it. Keep in mind I have no idea what kind of file you are actually working with.

```
long long id = 1000;
std::string name = "name";
std::string surname = "overflow";
std::string degree = "internet";
unsigned char sex = 'c';
int birthdate = 256;

ofstream outfile("test.txt", ios::binary);
if (outfile.is_open())
{
    const char* idBytes = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&id));

    const char* nameBytes = name.c_str();
    const char* surnameBytes = surname.c_str();
    const char* degreeBytes = degree.c_str();

    const char* birthdateBytes = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&birthdate));

    outfile.write(idBytes, sizeof(id));
    outfile.write(nameBytes, name.length());
    outfile.write(surnameBytes, surname.length());
    outfile.write(degreeBytes, degree.length());
    outfile.put(sex);
    outfile.write(birthdateBytes, sizeof(birthdate));

    outfile.flush();
    outfile.close();
}
```

and here is how I am going to output it, which to me seems to be coming out as expected.

```
ifstream infile("test.txt", std::ifstream::ate | ios::binary);
if (infile.is_open())
{
    std::size_t fileSize = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        char c = infile.get();
        std::cout << c;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```